# How to known which time zone the system is using

Tags: c, linux, timezone

I'm doing some code where I need to known which time zone is active in the system (I'm working on a Linux SO):

- My first aproach was to check `TZ` enviroment var,it's empty unless I set it (for instance calling tzset)
- After that I try  `extern long timezone` (time.h) but this variable is always 0.
- Finally I calculate the difference of my timezone and UTC+0 but I don't get my real timezone because I don't known if daylight saving apply

I'm pretty sure that there are a easy (and most consistent) way to achieve this. I'm looking for something like "Europe/Paris" or "UTC+2" or something like that

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13804095/1606345

Comment: @KeineLust thanks, but I'm looking to timezone not the current offset to GMT. Anyway it's a good clue

Comment: Here is what I'm using: https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date/blob/master/tz.cpp#L3030-L3097  This is C++ but you could translate it to C easily enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a starting point, I would suggest this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void)
{
  char str[64];
  time_t timer;
  struct tm * ptm;
  timer = time(NULL);
  ptm = localtime(&timer); 
  strftime(str, sizeof(str), "%Z", ptm);
  printf("TZ: %s\n", str);
  return(0);
}
```

Comment: I don't think `sizeof(str-1)` does what you think it does.

Comment: It's almost what I wanted!, I get 'CET' for Paris , EST  for NY and CST for Costa Rica.

Comment: The minus 1 is not needed.  `strftime(str, sizeof str , "%Z", ptm);` is OK.  Better to check its return value.

Comment: @JoanEsteban How is this answer not what you wanted?  If the result is `"CET"`, _that_ is the name of the time zone as code understands it.  The name is _not_ `"Europe/Paris"`.  On another system, code may return   `"Europe/Paris"` as that is the name on that system.  How did you set  your system to "Paris"?  Perhaps that is the short-coming?

Comment: @Joan. If you want to go further, you need to play with the so called Olson database (after Arthur David Olson), located in /usr/share/zoneinfo. Your /etc/localtime should be a symlink to the time zone in the form Asia/Tokyo for example in the Olson database. With a few system calls, you should trace this easily. This does not apply on limited embedded Linux systems, where TZ is still used in a condensed form, called POSIX TZ string (like EST5EDT,M03.2.0,M11.1.0)

Answer (score 1):

Option 1)

timezone and tzname could be available after call tzset():

```
cout << "Before tzset: " << timezone << " " << tzname[0] << " " << tzname[1] << endl;
tzset();
cout << "After tzset: " << timezone << " " << tzname[0] << " " << tzname[1] << endl;
```

outputs (today, in Europe):

```
Before tzset: 0 GMT GMT
After tzset: -3600 CET CEST
```

Option 2) Some versions of "struct tm" (GNU, BSD, ...) contains fields "tm_zone" and "tm_isdst":

```
time_t timer;
struct tm *ptm;

timer = time(NULL);
ptm = localtime( &timer );
cout << ptm->tm_zone <<  " " << ptm->tm_isdst << endl;

timer -= 60*24*3600; // 60 days ago
ptm = localtime( &timer );
cout << ptm->tm_zone <<  " " << ptm->tm_isdst << endl;
```

outputs:

```
CET 0
CEST 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The `date +%Z` command shows the current timezone, but what you actually want is to set it correctly. First remove the current timezone file:

```
# rm -f /etc/localtime
```

Then set the correct one for your timezone:

```
# ln -s /usr/share/zoneinfo/<your-time-zone-here> /etc/localtime
```

Do an `ls /usr/share/zoneinfo/` to see the available timezones. For me it's `/usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Amsterdam`.

Then verify using the abovementioned `date` command.

Comment: That is not what I'm asking for, I already have done that to check my code with severals Timezones, but I want to get my timezone from C program (and, of course, I can't  read /etc/localtime link because It's not always a link)