# I'm trying to build an RFC3339 timestamp in C. How do I get the timezone offset?

Tags: c, time, timezone, timezone-offset, rfc3339

I'm attempting to put together an RFC3339 timestamp which will be used to write a certain entry to a database. That would be formatted as, for example, 2004-10-19 10:23:54+02, where the +02 is the offset in hours from GMT. It's this offset which is proving troublesome - I can't seem to derive this value in C.

Here is the code I'm using. When I try to build, it says the tm struct doesn't have a member named tm_gmtoff:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    time_t now = time(NULL);
    struct tm *tm;
    int off_sign;
    int off;
    if ((tm = localtime(&now)) == NULL) {
            return -1;
    }
    off_sign = '+';
    off = (int) tm->tm_gmtoff;
    if (tm->tm_gmtoff < 0) {
            off_sign = '-';
            off = -off;
    }
    printf("%d-%d-%dT%02d:%02d:%02d%c%02d:%02d",
    tm->tm_year + 1900, tm->tm_mon + 1, tm->tm_mday,
    tm->tm_hour, tm->tm_min, tm->tm_sec,
    off_sign, off / 3600, off % 3600);
    return 0;
```

}

Comment: Have you tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13804095/get-the-time-zone-gmt-offset-in-c ?

Comment: Yes, and I see the following error: 'struct tm' has no member named 'tm_gmtoff'; did you mean 'tm_mon'?

Comment: Additionally, I see the following when I run the code at the answer you linked: warning: implicit declaration of function 'localtime_r'

Comment: Re: "where the +02 is the offset in hours".  How do you want to handle offsets that are −2:30 or +05:45?

Comment: @K.Haskins `struct tm` _may_ have a member  `tm_gmtoff`.  It is implementation defined.

Comment: Which C are you running on what platform? Not all C compilers have what you need.

Comment: I'm using minGW on Windows 10

Comment: Does your std library not have [strftime](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strftime.3.html)?

Comment: BTW: `off % 3600` does not provide the _minutes_ offset.  Certain you want `(off % 3600)/60`.

Comment: Rather than `printf("%d-%d-%d...`, I'd expect `printf("%04d-%02d-%02d`

Comment: Like @chux-reinstate-monica stated, `off % 3600` does not provide minutes offset. But instead of doing `(off % 3600)/60`, a simple `off % 60` will suffice.

Answer (score 3):

> to build an RFC3339 timestamp in C

If a *string* is the goal, the easy solution is to use `strftime()`.

```
  time_t now;
  time(&now);
  struct tm *p = localtime(&now);
  char buf[100];
  size_t len = strftime(buf, sizeof buf - 1, "%FT%T%z", p);
  // move last 2 digits
  if (len > 1) {
    char minute[] = { buf[len-2], buf[len-1], '\0' };
    sprintf(buf + len - 2, ":%s", minute);
  }
  printf("\"%s\"\n", buf);
```

Output

```
"2018-11-21T13:21:08-06:00"
```

---

> How do I get the timezone offset?
> When I try to build, it says the tm struct doesn't have a member named tm_gmtoff:

The `tm_gmtoff` is an optional extra member of `struct tm`.  When available, that or some other similar implementation dependent member would be good to use.

---

With access to `strftime()` and `"%z"`, as suggeted by [@jwdonahue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48771851/im-trying-to-build-an-rfc3339-timestamp-in-c-how-do-i-get-the-timezone-offset#comment84546881_48771851).
`"%z"` available since C99.

> %z is replaced by the offset from UTC in the ISO 8601 format ‘‘−0430’’ (meaning 4
> hours 30 minutes behind UTC, west of Greenwich), or by no characters if no time
> zone is determinable.  C11 §7.27.3.5 3

```
int main(void) {
  time_t now;
  time(&now);
  struct tm *p = localtime(&now);
  char buf[6];
  strftime(buf, sizeof buf, "%z", p);
  int h, m;
  sscanf(buf, "%3d%d", &h, &m);
  if (h < 0)  m = -m;
  printf("Minute difference %d\n", h*60+m);
}
```

Output for [CT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_Time_Zone)

```
Minute difference -360
```

---

Lacking the above choices, code can deduce the timezone offset directly from  `localtime()` and `gmttime()`: do a `struct tm` subtraction.

The below takes advantage that a difference in timestamps does not exceed 1 day near January 1st.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

// Return difference in seconds.
long tz_offset(time_t t) {
  struct tm *p = localtime(&t);
  if (p == NULL) return INT_MIN;
  printf("%s", asctime(p));
  struct tm local = *p;
  p = gmtime(&t);
  if (p == NULL) return INT_MIN;
  printf("%s", asctime(p));
  struct tm gmt = *p;

  int day = local.tm_yday - gmt.tm_yday;
  if (local.tm_year > gmt.tm_year) {
    day = 1;
  } else if (local.tm_year < gmt.tm_year) {
    day = -1;
  }
  int hour = day*24 + (local.tm_hour - gmt.tm_hour);
  if (local.tm_isdst) {
    ; // no adjustment
  }
  long diff = (hour*60L + (local.tm_min - gmt.tm_min))*60 + (local.tm_sec - gmt.tm_sec);
  return diff;
}

int main(void) {
  time_t now;
  time(&now);
  printf("tz offset %g\n", tz_offset(now)/3600.0);
  
  // Check time 6-months from now, maybe different daylight setting
  struct tm *p = localtime(&now);
  p->tm_mon += 6;
  now = mktime(p);
  printf("tz offset %g\n", tz_offset(now)/3600.0);
  return 0;
}
```

Sample output for [CT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_Time_Zone)

```
Tue Feb 13 11:40:00 2018
Tue Feb 13 17:40:00 2018
tz offset -6
Mon Aug 13 12:40:00 2018
Mon Aug 13 17:40:00 2018
tz offset -5
```

---

To print the timezone offset per [RFC3339](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339) given `hour, minute`:

```
  // Alway print the sign and leading zero digits
  printf("%+02d:%02d", hours, abs(minute));
```

---

See also [What's the difference between ISO 8601 and RFC 3339 Date Formats?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/522251/2410359)

Comment: The `strftime` call you give in the first section does not produce a valid RFC3339 string. In RFC3339, the time zone needs to be formatted with a colon. For your example to be valid, it would have to look like this: `"2018-02-13T12:32:52-06:00"`