# How to get the timezone in C99?

Tags: c, datetime, timezone, c99

I compile C using the C99 version, and I want to try and output the timezone of the given time.

The IDE I use gives GMT+0 as the timezone, but I want to somehow output it with `struct tm`.

So I followed the instructions from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13804095/get-the-time-zone-gmt-offset-in-c/13804869#13804869) and made this program:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    time_t present = time(NULL);
    struct tm now = *localtime(&present);
    now.tm_mon += 1;
    now.tm_year += 1900;
    struct tm t = {0};
    localtime_r(&present, &t);
    printf("%i/%i/%i %i:%i:%i from %s\n", now.tm_mon, now.tm_mday, now.tm_year, now.tm_hour, now.tm_min, now.tm_sec, t.tm_zone);
}
```

And it seems like I got 2 errors here:

1. `implicit declaration of function 'localtime_r' is invalid in C99`
2. `no member named 'tm_zone' in 'struct tm'`

So I checked the [IDE Manual](https://manual.cs50.io/), and find that `localtime_r` actually exists, and is part of the `<time.h>` library.

So now I'm wondering if the IDE's confused or something. I don't know how to fix it either.

> This might get closed as it might "need debugging details", but read more.

Because of this whole situation, how can I get the timezone (maybe even the offset) in C99 and get it to be outputted with `printf()`?

Comment: I don't care about your "I didn't want to include the header files in the code shown above.", since the `#include`s are very much relevant.

Comment: @Cheatah You can delete your comment now.

Comment: `localtime_r` is not part of the standard library - it’s an extension offered by specific implementations, and its declaration is not exposed by default in those implementations.  If your implementation actually supports it, you’ll have to define the macro `_POSIX_SOURCE` before including `time.h` to make it available.

Comment: @JohnBode You can make that an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, `localtime_r` is not part of the standard library - it's an extension offered by some implementations, and by default its declaration is not exposed in those implementations.  To make it available, you'll have to define the macro `_POSIX_SOURCE` *before* including `time.h` to make it available.  An easy way to do that is on the command line, like so:

```
gcc -o tz -D_POSIX_SOURCE -std=c11 -pedantic -Wall -Werror tz.c
```

otherwise, just define it in your source before including `time.h`:

```
#define _POSIX_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
```

Secondly, if all you're interested in is the local time zone then there's an easier way to do this - get the current time:

```
time_t t = time( NULL );
```

then use both `localtime` and `gmtime` to get the broken down time for the current time zone and UTC:

```
struct tm *local = localtime( &t );
struct tm *zulu  = gmtime( &t );
```

Then compute the difference between the `tm_hour` members of `local` and `zulu`, and that's your time zone.

```
int tz = zulu->tm_hour - local->tm_hour;
```

You'll want to check `local->tm_isdst` to account for daylight savings, but that should at least get you started.